# replace numbers with word in list

Tags: list, recursion, lisp

I am trying to replace all the numbers of list with a word and keep the words as originaly: for example: (spam '(i ate 1 and he ate 1 too)) output: i ate food and he ate food too. in my function i first check the base case if the list is empty.
Then I check the characters in the list recursively and if they are numbers convert them to some word food for example. and finally i check if the characters are chars keep it. The code is not working and giving errors even though I think the logic is correct. So here is my code

```
(defun spam(list)
    (if (null list) nil
        (if (first numberp list) 'food (spam(rest list))
            ((first list)(spam(rest list)))
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CL-USER > (subst-if 'food #'numberp '(i ate 1 and he ate 1 too))
(I ATE FOOD AND HE ATE FOOD TOO)
```

Answer (score 2):

In the original function, the second conditional should read

```
(if (numberp (first list) ...
```

not

```
(if (first numberp list) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than `'food (spam (rest list))`, you need `(cons 'food (spam (rest list)))`. Likewise for the other branch of the `if`.

Comment: (defun spam(list)
    (if (null list) nil
        (if (first numberp list) (cons'food (spam(rest list)))
            ((first list)(cons (spam(rest list))))
        )
    )
)  It is returning the same result as the initial one...

Comment: That should be `(cons (first list) (spam (rest list)))`, not `((first list) (cons (spam (rest list))))`.